# How to pre-initialize an ILifecycle's IObjectCache values?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

When implementing a custom StructureMap (2.6) lifecycle (by inheriting from `ILifecycle`), its responsibility is to return an `IObjectCache` instance - depending on how long the lifetime is, this can be a filled or an empty object cache.

But I want to pre-initialize that cache, so that at the start of the lifecycle, I can specify what instance to use for a specific interface, which StructureMap will then
keep returning for the duration of the lifecycle.

Right now, the only option I see to specify a specific instance is in the `ObjectFactory.Configure`:

```
StructureMap.ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
{
    x.For<IPluginExecutionContext>()
     .LifecycleIs(new PluginCallLifecycle())
     .Use(myExecutionContext);
}
```

But this would mean that I would have call Configure() every time an `ILifecycle` starts. For one thing, this isn't thread-safe in my situation, and to me it doesn't seem good practice to reconfigure the container like this every time.

How can I manually add a value to the `IObjectCache`, so that StructureMap will return that value for the duration of the ILifecycle?

I've looked at the `IObjectCache`'s methods, but most of them require a `StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance`, which doesn't seem trivial to create or obtain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to pre-fill the cache? StructureMap should do this for you when an instance of the `IPluginExecutionContext` is requested.

If you are simply trying to implement a lifecycle which keeps returning the same object for a given time and only then creates a new one, take a look at [this post by Adam Bar](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2014/06/structuremap-time-expiring-objects-cache.html).

If you want to accomplish something different, can you describe your scenario in more details?

**EDIT:**

If you *really* need the first cached object to be a specific instance (thought I don't know why you'd want that), you can also (maybe in addition to using the solution I linked to) change your registration to:

```
StructureMap.ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
{
    x.For<IPluginExecutionContext>()
     .LifecycleIs(new PluginCallLifecycle()) // or TimeExpiringLifecycle
     .Use(ctx => getMyExecutionContext(ctx));
}
```

where `getMyExecutionContext` would be a method which returns your predefined instance (`myExecutionContext`) on the first call and creates a new one on subsequent calls. Combined with Adam Bar's `TimeExpiringLifecycle`, this would give you a cached instance which changes every time a given timeout expires, while allowing you to manually inject the first cached instance.